# How to show text in UITextField in vertically center in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have iphone app in which i have textfield it works fine but problem is that it show text from top of text field i want it to be in center aligned verticaly. here is my code for textfield.

```
  herdTextFieldSecond=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(108,1052,259,36)];
herdTextFieldSecond.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentLeft;



herdTextFieldSecond.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    herdTextFieldSecond.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
herdTextFieldSecond.text=@"";
herdTextFieldSecond.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
herdTextFieldSecond.delegate=self;
herdTextFieldSecond.layer.borderWidth =1;
    herdTextFieldSecond.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    herdTextFieldSecond.layer.cornerRadius=5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code for vertical alignment of text in `UITextFiled` :

```
MyTextFieldName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```